# basic security tools and packages that should be installed on a public facing web server

Tags: server, security, firewall, ruby, nginx

I'm a newbie in this world and I do not have a lot of knowledge about how security works on Linux systems. I recently created a droplet on DigitalOcean with Ubuntu 13 and I've been setting it up by following some of the tutorials they have.

But I can see that there are a lot of security tools that do mostly the same thing, so I am unsure what I should install and configure. So far this is what I installed:

- [Disallow Root Access](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Security_Guide/s2-wstation-privileges-noroot.html)
- [SSH 2 Factor Authentication](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-authy-and-configure-two-factor-authentication-for-ssh)
- [UFW](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-setup-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-an-ubuntu-and-debian-cloud-server)
- [Fail2Ban](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-protect-ssh-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-12-04)
- [Tripwire](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-use-tripwire-to-detect-server-intrusions-on-an-ubuntu-vps)
- [DenyHosts](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-denyhosts-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Is this too much or maybe overreacting? And are any of the above unnecessary? Does anyone suggest some other tools besides the above that I should install?

**EDIT**: I ended up installing/setting up the following:

- [2 Factor Authentication (Authy)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-authy-and-configure-two-factor-authentication-for-ssh)
- [UFW (Firewall)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-setup-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-an-ubuntu-and-debian-cloud-server)
- [FSTAB (Secure Shared Memory) [Step 2]](http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-secure-ubuntu-1204-lts-server-part-1-basics)
- [Disallow Root Access [Step 3]](http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-secure-ubuntu-1204-lts-server-part-1-basics)
- [Protect SU [Step 4]](http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-secure-ubuntu-1204-lts-server-part-1-basics)
- [SYSCTL Settings (Harden Network) [Step 5]](http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-secure-ubuntu-1204-lts-server-part-1-basics)
- [IP Spoofing [Step 7]](http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-secure-ubuntu-1204-lts-server-part-1-basics)
- [DenyHosts (Prevent Brute Force Attacks)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-denyhosts-on-ubuntu-12-04)
- [Fail2Ban (Protect SSH)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-protect-ssh-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-12-04)
- [PSAD (Network Intrusion Detection)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-use-psad-to-detect-network-intrusion-attempts-on-an-ubuntu-vps)
- [Tripwire (Server Intrusion Detection)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-use-tripwire-to-detect-server-intrusions-on-an-ubuntu-vps)
- [RKHunter (Rootkit Guard)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-use-rkhunter-to-guard-against-rootkits-on-an-ubuntu-vps)
- [Apparmor (SELinux) [Step 17]](http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-secure-ubuntu-1204-lts-server-part-1-basics)

I hope that now I got a basic security setup running. Any input on what I am missing or what I should not use is appreciated.

Comment: Whether it is too much or too little depends entirely on what risks you are trying to mitigate. What are you planning to do with the server?

Comment: It's going to be a web server, it will run a public website and API (running on ruby with postgresql, memcached and redis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about process and policy as well as tools. I think you need a more holistic approach such as those outlined in the CIS benchmarks. I would consult the new Ubuntu one just released as well as the Apache one if you'll be running Apache as your web server.

**Ubuntu CIS Benchmark**

https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/downloads/show-single/?file=ubuntu1204.100

**Apache CIS Benchmark**

https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/downloads/show-single/?file=apache24.110

Comment: I will actually be running varnish on a machine, nginx on some other machines and a ruby http server on others. I'll take a look at the CIS benchmark though to see what is that about, thanks :)